# Triac doesn't triggering when the power jack pins switched?

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, triac

I built a power circuit with MOC3063 & BTA40600 for controlling heating element (2000 watts) according to the image. when I plug the jack in let's say one direction the circuit works like a charm ... but when I change the position of the jack (means Neutral & Phase) the triac doesn't work at all!
Where is the problem? any help would be helpful
regards[image]

Comment: (1) Add a photo of your circuit. You may have an error. (2) We have no idea if the control circuit is working. Reduce \$ R_{in} \$ and add a visible LED in series so you can tell if the control circuit is working. (3) It's good manners to link to datasheets of the devices you reference in your post so we don't have to look them up. Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: @Transistor thanks , I will test with your condition and will get back to you